# R, extract columns as vectors from grouped data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

Imagine you have this data frame

```
x <- c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4")

y <- c("red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "black", "pink", "purple", 
"orange")

df <- data.frame(x, y, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I cannot think of a way, preferably using dplyr, to extract the y column after grouping the data frame. Essentially I'd like to know what colors are in a1, in a2, in a3, and in a4, and store those results as separate vectors, ideally in a list.

I could do

```
colors.in.a1 <- df %>% filter(x == "a1") %>% pull(y)
```

for each of a1, a2, a3, a4, but that would take awhile with my real data. I was hoping that `pull()` would behave like `tally()`, perhaps returning a list of vectors that are named based on the grouping variable, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution using `dplyr` and `purrr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  split(.$x) %>% 
  map(pull, y)
```

> ```
> $a1
> [1] "red"   "black"
>
> $a2
> [1] "yellow" "pink"  
>
> $a3
> [1] "blue"   "purple"
>
> $a4
> [1] "green"  "orange"
> ```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(x = c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a1", "a2", "a3", 
"a4"), y = c("red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "black", "pink", 
"purple", "orange")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Really saved my day.

Answer (score 2):

With Base R only (thanks to @thelatemail's comment):

```
split(df$y, df$x)
```

or we can use `nest`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(data = data %>% map(pull, y)) %>%
  pull(data) %>%
  setNames(unique(x))
```

**Result:**

```
$a1
[1] "red"   "black"

$a2
[1] "yellow" "pink"  

$a3
[1] "blue"   "purple"

$a4
[1] "green"  "orange"
```

Comment: Why not just `split(df$y, df$x)` , or `split(df[["y"]], df[["x"]])` if you want to make it programmable?

Comment: @thelatemail You're right, I've always forgotten that `split` also works with splitting vectors.